# monacaにLINE、FB、Twitterの紹介機能を実装したい

Tags: monaca, facebook, twitter, twitter4j

家電量販店のアプリなどでLINE、FB、Twitterにアプリやアプリ内の記事を投稿する機能があるものがあるのですが色々と探してみたのですがmonacaで実装する方法が分かりません。。
AppSociallyというサービスはAndroidしか対応していないようなのでハイブリッドアプリでどのようにすればいいのか考えています。
皆様のアドバイスをいただければ幸いです。

どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

lineで本文を共有してもらうには以下のURL schemeを利用します。

```
line://msg/text/[ここに本文]
```

twitterで本文をツイートしてもらうには以下のURLを使用します。

```
https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=[ここに本文]
```

facebookでシェアしてもらうには以下のURLを使用します。

```
http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=[ここにURL]&t=[ここにタイトル]
```

Hatenaにエントリーしてもらうには以下のURLを使用します。

```
http://b.hatena.ne.jp/add?mode=confirm&url=[ここにURL]&title=[ここにタイトル]
```

Google+1ボタンを押してもらうには以下のURLを使用します。

```
https://plusone.google.com/_/+1/confirm?hl=ja&url=[ここにURL]
```

基本的に本文はhtmlspecialcharsなどを利用して特殊文字をHTMLエンティティに変換する必要があります。

これらのURLをアンカータグを利用してリンクして下さい。

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=こんにちは">
  Twitterで「こんにちは」とつぶやく
</a>
```

javascriptを利用して動的にURLを叩く事もできますが、ステップを挟まずに強制的に投稿するには各サイトにアプリケーション登録してアプリケーションのkeyとsecretを発行する必要があります。

Comment: 大変参考になりました！
どうもありがとうございました。

Comment: @akane さん。もしよろしければ解答にチェックを入れていただけると、回答者と質問者双方に評価ポイントが付きます。コミュニティの為にもなりますのでどうぞよろしくお願いします。